# What is the right word here? "It was impingent on him to act."

Tags: single-word-requests

"Impingent" obviously isn't the right word here. The word I'm thinking of means something like "required" or "imperative," but the same part of speech as "imposed."

"Requisite" fits, more or less, but that's not it.

I've explored the Concise Oxford American Thesaurus, with no luck.

Comment: I think the speaker probably had "incumbent" in mind.

Comment: Aha! That's it! I could not remember that word for the life of me!

Comment: incumbent: Cambridge dictionary: necessary:
[ + to infinitive ] It is incumbent upon (= necessary for) all of us to create a safe community. Too trivial to be an answer

Comment: I like _impingent_, though.  What could it mean? Not obeying social distancing rules? _Sir, you are impingent; please leave immediately._

Comment: @JohnLawler *Aw maa, not Aunt Sally! She always impinges my cheeks, and it hurts!"

Comment: @JohnLawler Apparently, it means "Striking against or upon." Who knew? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impingent

Comment: @AndyBonner Aunt Sally developed her vice-like finger grip from years of impinging the edges of her fruit pies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sven Yargs commented:

> I think the speaker probably had "incumbent" in mind.